# Problemas com limites de largura da banda

Tags: servidor

Tenho um site hospedado em um servidor (Kinghsot). Esse mesmo site, teve esse mês (de 01/fev até 16/fev) cerca de 2700 visitas, de acordo com o Google Analytics. O que acontece, é que isso gerou de tráfego mensal (até o dia 16) de quase 22GB, isso está normal?

Eu estava conferindo as estatísticas do servidor, e vi que os arquivos .JS estão com muitos hits, conforme imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pensei que talvez, poderia ser algum plugin, mas dei uma conferida e não há nada suspeito.
Lista de plugins que eu uso:

- Admin Menu Editor
- CloudFlare
- Disqus Comment System
- Facebook Comments
- Google AdSense
- Master Slider Pro
- Relevanssi
- Shareaholic | share buttons, analytics, related content
- Simple Image Sizes
- Templatera
- TinyMCE Advanced
- WPBakery Visual Composer (Artbees Modified Version)
- Yoast SEO

Imagem com os dados de tráfego:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara, tenta dar uma otimizada nos seus scripts, pelo menos de acordo com o tamamnho...
Pode tentar usar o PageSpeed (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) para avaliar as melhorias.

Em relação aos hits, acredito que possa ser algum plugin do seu próprio tema do WP.

Answer (score 2):

Em média, cada visualização está consumindo pouco mais de 8 Mega para 2700 visualizações consumirem 22GB. Parece condizente com o conteúdo do seu site?

Para melhorar isso, o jeito é otimizar mesmo (reduzir imagens, páginas, simplificar opções, etc).

Comment: Obrigado, vou verificar e ver se é isso. Instalar um plugin para otimizar as imagens.